# Ruby on Rails 4, incompatible character encodings: latin1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, latin1

I've a problem with charset encoding/decoding in my web application in rails 4.
i see word like "rappresentÃ²" or "Ã¨" in my webpage but i want to see "rappresentò" and "è".

this is my stack structure :

Server Os : Ubuntu 14.04,
mysql 
database : "foo" , 
table :"bar"

```
table description : 

|description 
| mediumtext
| latin1_swedish_ci 
| YES |....
```

this is my database config in rails

```
default: &default    adapter: mysql2    encoding: latin1    pool: 5    username: root    password: ****    socket: ....
```

in rails view

```
meta-charset is "ISO-8859-1"
```

Note:
 - i reflected the problem only on the server machine
 - when i connect to the database via ssh i saw the characters correctly

This is my output in rails console:

```
Bar.find(38).description
Il volume Ã¨ arricchito dalle illustrazioni di Jean-Jacques SempÃ©. "
```

Comment: You need to post the code the puts the characters into the page that you don't like.

Comment: mmm..are you sure that the code is necessary?
because I take the data from the controller and put them in the view...

Comment: Alright then, show me the console output of find() for one row where there is an "è".

Comment: this is my console output.    description field of foo.find(id) : " Claude Debussy (1862-1918) la cui musica rappresentÃ² . Il volume Ã¨ ".                "Ã¨ " is saved like "è" in database

Comment: No, not like that.  I want you to copy and paste the find command and its output into your question, then highlight it, and click on `{ }` to put code tags around it.  Secondly, I want you to post what encoding your browser is set to: in Chrome it's under View>Encoding.

Comment: i pasted "find command", my chrome encoding is "auto-detect / utf-8"

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your terminal's encoding is `ISO-8859-1`, and for the accented e, the string contains the sequence `\xC3\xA8`.  But in ISO-8859-1, you have this:

```
\xC3  --> Ã
\xA8  --> ¨
```

And, that is what you are seeing for the output in your ISO-8859-1 terminal.

In `UTF-8`, the sequence `\xC3\xA8` happens to represent one character: `è`.  So, that means you inserted the UTF-8 sequence `\xC3\xA8` in your database for `è`--instead of the `ISO-8859-1` sequence for `è`, which is `\xE8`.

```
UTF-8:       è  ->  \xC3\xA8
ISO-8859-1:  è  ->  \xE8
```

Because all characters in `ISO-8859-1` are represented by one byte, and because the sequence `\xC3\xA8` represents two bytes, that means any `ISO-8859-1` device is going to interpret that sequence as the character `\xC3`, namely `Ã`, followed by the character `\xA8`, which is `¨`.

Unfortunately, the strings you inserted in your database were encoded in `UTF-8`.  Therefore, you should have specified the encoding for your database as `UTF-8`to begin with; or you should have converted your strings from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` before inserting them in your database:

```
2.0.0-p481 :029 > str = "R\xC3\xA8"
 => "RÃ¨"    #Terminal set to 'ISO-8859-1' encoding

2.0.0-p481 :030 > str.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 

2.0.0-p481 :031 > str = str.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')
 => "R\xE8" 

2.0.0-p481 :032 > str.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1> 

2.0.0-p481 :033 > puts str
Rè
 => nil
```

Comment: My terminal's encoding is UTF-8. i don't understand because when i launch the find command in local machine rails show character correctly (my output is "è") while the same command via ssh is "Ã¨"

Comment: Then, apply all my comments to your remote host. Alternatively, change the encoding of your terminal to `ISO-8859-1`. The bottom line is that you inserted `UTF-8` data into your database, namely the sequence `\xC3\xA8` to represent an accented e; therefore any `ISO-8859-1` device will display that sequence as two junk characters. On the other hand, a `UTF-8` device will see the sequence `\xC3\xA8` as a single character: an accented e.